# Removing an attribute from xml using XSL transformation

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

> I'm using xsl transformation
>
> [Document Title]
>
> Document Body
>
> I want to remove attribute 'regionTitleFriendly' from the element
> region
>
> this is what i have been trying
>
> <xsl:template match = "sc:region[@xt:regionTitleFriendly='Region
> Title']">
> <xsl:attribute name="id">
> <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
> </xsl:attribute>
> <xsl:attribute name="type">
> <xsl:value-of select="./@type"/>
> </xsl:attribute>
> <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>   </xsl:template>
>
> but its not working can anybody please help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "remove" an attribute from your output, the usual way is to "match" that attribute with an "empty" template:

Using your matching rule, can convert it trivially to an "empty" template.
This template only matches those `xt:region` attributes within the `sc:region` element that have the value `'Region Title'`:

```xml
  <xsl:template match="sc:region/@xt:regionTitleFriendly[. eq 'Region Title']"/>
```

If you rather remove **all** `@xt:regionTitleFriendly` attributes from `sc:region` elements, then you can use:

```xml
  <xsl:template match="sc:region/@xt:regionTitleFriendly"/>
```

Will this work for you?